# how to download a file in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have uploaded some files which are stored in /media/documents. I've also set the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py and have given appropriate url in urls.py.
The files are uploaded through a form and now I need to download the uploaded files.
Im confused on how to download from the browser. Can someone please help me, I am new to django.

## models

```
class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_diagnoised = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    uploaded_by = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    downloaded_by = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")`
```

## views.py

```
def index(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    uid = request.user.id
    usern = request.user.username
    if Profile.objects.filter(role='Doctor', id=uid):#file upload
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.uploaded_by = usern
                post.save()
                return redirect('index')
        else:
            form = DocumentForm()
            no_diagno = Document.objects.filter(is_diagnoised=False, uploaded_by=usern)
            is_diagno = Document.objects.filter(is_diagnoised=True, uploaded_by=usern)
            context = {
                'ndg':no_diagno,
                'ydg':is_diagno,
                'form': form
            }
        return render(request, 'upload.html', context)

    else:#file download
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RadioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.downloaded_by = usern
                post.is_diagnoised = 'True'
                post.save()
                return redirect('index')
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = RadioForm()
            no_diagno = Document.objects.filter(is_diagnoised=False)
            is_diagno = Document.objects.filter(is_diagnoised=True)
            context = {
                'ndg':no_diagno,
                'ydg':is_diagno,
                'form': form
            }
        return render(request, 'index-rad.html', context)

def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, media/documents)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read())
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' +os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

## index-rad.html

```
{% for n in ndg %}
<ol>
<li>{{n.description}} <a href="{% url 'download' %}">download</a></li>
</ol>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link to know more about asking questions here on SO as your question isn't very descriptive or doesn't includes samples of your efforts or examples.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You don't really need to have django handle file serving. That can be done better by a web server such as nginx.

Comment: Your `download` view contains two undefined variables `media` divided by `documents`. Is that supposed to be a string? And you never use the provided `path` argument. It's quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very informative, but as i undestand, you need url of file in your teplate. For this, you can simply use {{ myfile.url }}.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you help me. Im stuck at this point.